# Calling external application from JAVA in solaris

Tags: java, solaris-10

I want to call a c executable application from my java code. I found a solution as I can use :

```
String[] arg = new String[] {"cmd","/c","add"};
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(arg);
```

But this is only working on the windows environment.

I want to run it on solaris environment.

I searched on google but I could not find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

there is no `cmd` on Solaris. just use the full path to your `add` binary.

Comment: I tried that but it is not running the binary ..how can i do it or Is any other way to do it...  @ukuLoskit

Comment: what makes you think it is not running the binary?

Comment: beacuse my binary prints a string which is i am reading by using inputstramreader.  so it is printing nothing..